# IntelliJ IDEA - how fold for else block and catch block default?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'd love to have a way of IntelliJ letting me fold for if/else's else statements and try..catch's catch blcok default after open a .java file. But, I can't seem to find a way to config it automatically. ?

Comment: there is a keyboard shortcut `preferences > keymap > code > folding > collapse all`

Answer (score 1):

File -> New -> Edit File templates
Then you can add template according to your requirement.

Then when you create a class you have to select that created template.
Example:

```
 public class ${NAME} {
    void method() {
      if() {

      } else {

      }
      try {

      } catch(Exception ex) {

     }
  }
}
```